# tkdiff and diff does not work because of "\0" [Perl]

Tags: perl, diff

I stumbled upon the following piece of code in Perl:

```
my $val = $x->insertEl($data) or die $y->ErrorMessage();
print "\0$val\0";
```

What does `\0` mean in this scenario?
This script creates a debug log which the `\0$val\` is written into this log (I changed the `debugFun()` into `print` so it will be easier to explain). If I try to tkdiff with some other file it will fail with the following error:

```
diff failed: Files file1 and file2 differ. Child process exited abnormally
```

Also if I use the regular diff command it will print:

```
diff failed: Files file1 and file2 differ.
```

If I'll remove the `\0` it will print properly, and tkdiff and diff will work. So the problem is `\0` but why?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Binary

Comment: _Any_ idea, clue, or suspicion of why that is there?

Comment: With GNU `diff`, you can use `-a` or `--text` to force a text comparison (i.e. to get the usual output).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is padding the value with [null characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character).  While they do have some uses I am not sure what they do for a living in a log file.

As melpomene's link to [diffutils#Binary](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Binary) shows those tools are affected by the presence of these characters, and firstly by deciding that a file is binary. The manual offers `-a` switch under which `diff` still compares files as text, but this only helps by reporting differences in more detail; the files *are* different

```
perl -wE'say "noway"'   > t1.out
perl -wE'say "no\0way"' > t2.out
wc -c t1.out t2.out              #--> 6 and 7
```

So you'd have to remove those null characters.

If there is a good reason for them to be printed then this is one way to clean them out

```
perl -pe's/\x00//g' t2.out > nonull_t2.out
```

otherwise just change the print so that they are not there in the first place.